# Generate and download a csv file via axios with Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, csv, axios, laravel-9

I am working with Laravel 9.
From Axios, I call a route, which generates an array of arrays, to create a csv. How can I download the csv without having to save it previously on the server?
With the following code, I get it to generate and download it, correct csv format, and it occupies about 14kb. But I can't open it with any program (excel, vscode,notepad...), I think because of encoding problems ¿?.

on server:

```
$full = array_merge($header,$lines); 
    
$headers = array(
    "Content-type" => "text/csv",
    "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=file.csv",
    "Pragma" => "no-cache",
    "Content-Encoding" => "UTF-8",
    "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    "Expires" => "0"
);

$callback = function() use($full) {
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    //fputs($file, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) )); same result
    fputcsv($file, $full);    
    fclose($file);
};

return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

And axios call on client:

```
axios.post('{{ route("shiple.table") }}', filters)
            .then(function (response) {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'file.csv');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
  
        });
```

If I open it with notepad, it looks scrambled: Ï à¡± á ; þÿ

Answer (score 0):

In the Axios try this

```
axios.post('{{ route("shiple.table") }}', filters, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}) # changed
    .then(function (response) {
        const data = new Uint8Array(response.data); # changed
        const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'}); # changed
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.csv');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

---

Edit 01

```
axios.post('{{ route("shiple.table") }}', filters, {
    responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(function (response) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' }));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.csv');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thx, but with these modifications I still have the same problem. Vscode for example: "is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding"

Comment: run the code and check

Comment: I have run the code, it downloads the file correctly, but I cannot open it with the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the edit 01. I have tried, and still with the same result. I have uploaded the file to a "file encoding detector", and it is correctly in utf-8. But when I open it pe. with notepad I keep seeing crazy characters